# Is there a way to replace kdm with gdm?

Tags: kubuntu, login-screen, gdm

Well i tried kubuntu not long ago , didnt liked it and purged it from my system,
except one thing, I still have the kde login screen, is there anyway to get my gnome login screen back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply execute

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and select gdm instead of kdm.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can install gdm and choose desktop when you want to login

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```